# custom validation with javascript in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I'm new to MVC3. I have problem in custom validation, for example

In my BasicInfoViewModel.cs,

```
[Required]
    [Display(Name = "State", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global))]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "City", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global))]
    public string City { get; set; }
```

In my BasicDetailsView.cshtml,

```
<label>
<span class="td">@Application.Resources.Global.State</span>
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["State"])
</label>
<label>
<span class="td">@Application.Resources.Global.City</span>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.City, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["City"])
</label>
```

If the **state** property returns **true**, then only **"City"** is required. If not, **City** is not required, then the textbox should be diabled.
I'm not using *EditorFor*, using *DropDownListFor* because i'm using plain html. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
Thanks...

Comment: `I'm not using EditorFor, using TextBoxFor` - Where is this `TextBoxFor`? I can't see it in the code you have shown. All I can see is 2 dropdown lists (which by the way are wrong because you are using the same property name for both the value and the items).

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, corrected. How can we do this?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov my ViewData["city"] has a collection of SelectItem which has a different id, value for each.

Comment: But then you should not use `City` as first argument of your DropDown. Or rename the value in your ViewData to `ViewData["cities"]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`MVC Foolproof`](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) is a set of validation data annotations that extend the existing ones and provide additional functionality. For example the `[RequiredIfNotEmpty]` attribute from this package is quite suitable for your scenario as it allows for conditional validation.

```
[Display(Name = "State", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global))]
public string State { get; set; }

[RequiredIfNotEmpty("State")]
[Display(Name = "City", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global))]
public string City { get; set; }
```

Now the State property is optional. But if it has some value then the City property is required.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [RequiredIfAttribute](https://gist.github.com/1547191). To make your city dropdownlist disabled - use jquery. For checking if data is valid you have js method $("selector")*.valid()* which returns 0 or 1 and also shows validation message for specified field